# Issue with font not displaying

Tags: html, css, fonts

This portion of code does not work on my site. It still shows the default font. I think it is a minor error on my behalf, but I can't figure out where I went wrong. Can someone please help me point it out?

You can view the page at www.mh-rp.com or refer to image below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rs6eN.jpg)

```
    <div class="maintext">Mulholland Roleplay</div>
<a class="mainbutton" href="https://www.forum.mh-rp.com/wiki/game-server/"><li><i class="fa fa-gamepad"></i> Play Now</li></a>

@font-face
{
font-family: "BigNoodleTitling";
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: url("/fonts/BigNoodleTitling.woff"), format("woff");
}
@font-face
{
font-family: "BigNoodleTitling Oblique";
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: url("/fonts/BigNoodleTitling Oblique.woff"), format("woff");
}

.maintext
{
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
color: white;
font-family: "BigNoodleTitling Oblique", "Arial", sans-serif;
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
font-size: 72px;
}

.mainbutton
{
position: absolute;
top: 60%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
color: white;
font-family: "BigNoodleTitling", "Arial", sans-serif;
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
font-size: 32px;
border-color: white;
border-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: it's hard to say.. as it's difficult to reproduce this issue, given the issue.  there is such a thing as font caching.. there's also the question to whether that font file is accessible at that uri pathing.

Comment: Make sure that your fonts `url` are correct try to inspect them and open that in browser

Comment: I changed the paths but it still doesn't work
src: url("../fonts/big_noodle_titling.woff"), format("woff");

src: url("../fonts/big_noodle_titling_oblique.woff"), format("woff");

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in coding but I am pretty sure you have to use the @import method first on top of your code. I believe you can get these code from google fonts.

```
     @import           url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');
```

Answer (score 0):

.woff font extension is not enough.
I link my fonts the following way, meant for various browsers:

First check your .ttf file how your font is labeled.  Is it one word bignoodletitling or Big Noodle Titling.  So you enter that name to 'font-family' exactly as in your yourfontname.ttf file.

```
font-family: "Big Noodle Titling";


Inside CSS file:
* BIG NOODLE TITLING */ 
@font-face {
font-family: "BigNoodleTitling or perhaps Big Noodle Titling";
src: url("fonts/bignoodletitling.eot");
src: url("fonts/bignoodletitling.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), /* EOT file for IE6-8 */
     url("../fonts/bignoodletittling.woff") format("woff"), /* Firefox 3.6+, IE9, Chrome 6+, Safari 5.1+ */
     url("../fonts/bignoodletitling.woff2") format("woff2"),  /* Modern browsers  */
     url("fonts/bignoodletitling.ttf") format("truetype"),  /* TTF file for CSS3 browsers -- Safari 3-5, Chrome4+, Firefox 3.5, Opera 10+ */
     url("fonts/bignoodletitling.svg#futura") format("svg");
font-weight: 400;
font-style: normal;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
```

}

If you have BigNoodleTitling font Oblique, then you will need to prepare the css style sheet the same as above which would be for the oblique, because that is a separate class.

You will need for your font all or most of the above online fonts meant for various browsers.  You can obtain your web font also through Webfont Squirrel website and go to 'Webfont Generator'.

Then, add the following line to your .htaccess file:

```
#BEGIN REQUIRED FOR WEBFONTS
#BIGNOODLETITLING
AddType fonts/bignoodletitling/ .ttf
AddType fonts/bignoodletitling/ .eot
AddType fonts/bignoodletitling/ .otf
AddType fonts/bignoodletitling/ .woff
AddType fonts/bignoodletitling/ .woff2
AddType fonts/bignoodletitling/ .svg
```

Try to obtain the above font.extensions so that universally, your font becomes accessible and viewable on various browsers the way you want it.